# Quartz : What happens to misfires when a trigger is rescheduled?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, threadpool, quartz

So consider

1. I have scheduled a Job J1 and Trigger T1 with thread pool allocated to quartz with 3 threads.
2. The T1 is scheduled to execute the job every day at 5 A.M. with misfire instruction to run all the jobs immediately.
3. If my server was in shut down state for 15 days there would 15 misfires which will run immediately when servers start.
4. Now when the server will start 3 misfired job will start executing and rest 12 will be queued.
5. At the same time, I reschedule Trigger T1 to execute Job at 6 A.M.

Is there a possibility that rescheduling of the trigger is done before the misfired jobs are queued and all the misfired job is lost?

Is there a possibility that only a few jobs are queued and rest is lost since the Trigger is rescheduled in between?